# Inequality between consecutive prime gaps

Tags: nt.number-theory

Let $g_n=p_{n+1}-p_n $be the $n$-th prime gap. In searching for the function $f_n$ such that the sequence $\lbrace{g_n^{1/f_n}}\rbrace$is strictly decreasing (like in the case of Firoozbakht conjecture for sequence $\lbrace{p_n^{1/n}}\rbrace$ ), I came to the inequality:

$$g_{n+1}< 2\log^2(n+1)\log g_n \text{ or } \frac{g_{n+1}}{\log^2(n+1)}< 2\log\ g_n$$

which  seem to be valid for $n>4$. But later, in spite of eforts I could not prove this. If the Twin prime conjecture is true, then we can take $g_n=2$ for infinitely many $n$  and letting in the same time  $g_{n+1}$ tend to infinity. So we could write:

$$\frac{g_{n+1}}{\log^2(n+1)}< 2\log 2\approx1.3863 \text{ for infinitely many } n$$

If we supose that the choosing   $g_{n+1}$ is arbitrary, not dependent on  $g_n=2$, then it is plausible to write

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \sup\frac{g_n}{\log^2 n}< 1.3863$$

which seem to be in agreement with  (A.Granville ):

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\sup\frac{g_n}{\log^2 n} \geqslant 1.1229$$

Comment: I see no question marks in this post. What are you asking?

Comment: also, it is very easy to use "\log" to format properly.

Comment: Since $g_n\ll n$, your inequality would imply $g_n=O(\log^3 n)$, way beyond what is currently possible to prove with existing methods.

Comment: My question is: could $\frac{g_{n+1}}{log^{2}(n+1)}< 2log\ g_{n}$ be proved , or is there a plausible "heuristic" in favour of this inequality.

Comment: What exactly led you to these conclusions ? Just numerical testing ? Or is there an argument ?
It seems arbitrary compared to asking for the best proven result till now.
Put it in favorites but no +1 for now.